# Reorder json in js

Tags: javascript, json

I am building a tree, and the order I want is name, desc, then children.
So the json I got is in different order. How do you reorder it or is there a better way to write this code, taking consideration of multiple branches, and may be extra element can be add to the input?

So here is my code:

```
var arry = [{   
        "name": "J", 
        "target": "L",
        "desc": "2"
    },

    {
        "name": "L",    
        "target": "A",    
        "desc": "1"    
    },    
    {  
        "name": "S",  
        "target": "L",  
        "desc": "3"  
    }

];

function toJSON(data) {   
    var root = data.find(function(x) {   
        return !data.some(function(y) {  
            return y.name === x.target  
        });
}).target;
    console.log(root)



    var desc = data.find(function(x) {

        return !data.some(function(y) {

            return y.name === x.target

        });

    }).desc;




    var b = data.reduce(function(acc, x) {

        acc[x.target] = acc[x.target] || [];

        acc[x.target].push(x.name);

        return acc;



    }, {});  
    var tree = buildTree(root, b);   
    function buildTree(name, branches, desc) {
        var tree = {
            'name': name
        }; 
        if (branches[name]) {   
            tree.children = branches[name].map(function(x) {
                return buildTree(x, branches, desc)
            });
            for (var child in branches[name]) {
                var x = arry.find(function(i) {
                    return (i.name === branches[name][child] && i.target === name)    
                })    
                tree.children[child].desc = x.desc    
            }    
        }
        return tree;
    }
    if (tree.name === root) {    
        tree.desc = root   
    }
    for (var i in tree) {
         console.log(i)  
    }   
    return tree;
} // JavaScript name code  
var a = toJSON(arry)

console.log(JSON.stringify(a, null, 2))
```

The result I got is:

```
{
  "name": "A",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "L",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "J",
          "desc": "2"
        },
        {
          "name": "S",
          "desc": "3"
        }
      ],
      "desc": "1"
    }
  ],
  "desc": "A"
}
```

The result I want is:

```
 {
      "name": "A",
      "desc": "A",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "L",
          "desc": "1",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "J",
              "desc": "2"
            },
            {
              "name": "S",
              "desc": "3"
            }
          ]
       }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Why does the order matter?

Comment: I am writing for a visualization in d3.js for power bi. I had it working when I only have name and children with no desc. I don't know why after adding desc in the json, its not working anymore. I have checked rest of the code, 100% correct. So my last guess is order matter??? So is there a way to reorder it or a better way to write this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the question "Why does order matter"

But if you really want...

When creating object literals the keys/properties remain in the order in which they are/were defined (unless the keys are integers, then they will be in numerical order). On the line where you create your tree node you define an object but only put the `name` property on it. You then add `children`, then finally set the `desc` property.  If you instead define your object right away they will have that order and you can later mutate the values however you want.

```
const tree = {
  name,
  desc: undefined,
  children: undefined,
};
```

[image: Edit define-tree-node-shape]

```js
var arry = [
  {
    name: "J",
    target: "L",
    desc: "2"
  },

  {
    name: "L",
    target: "A",
    desc: "1"
  },
  {
    name: "S",
    target: "L",
    desc: "3"
  }
];

function toJSON(data) {
  var root = data.find(function(x) {
    return !data.some(function(y) {
      return y.name === x.target;
    });
  }).target;
  console.log(root);

  var desc = data.find(function(x) {
    return !data.some(function(y) {
      return y.name === x.target;
    });
  }).desc;

  var b = data.reduce(function(acc, x) {
    acc[x.target] = acc[x.target] || [];
    acc[x.target].push(x.name);
    return acc;
  }, {});

  var tree = buildTree(root, b);

  function buildTree(name, branches, desc) {
    // define your tree node shape here
    var tree = {
      name,
      desc: undefined,
      children: undefined
    };

    if (branches[name]) {
      tree.children = branches[name].map(function(x) {
        return buildTree(x, branches, desc);
      });
      for (var child in branches[name]) {
        var x = arry.find(function(i) {
          return i.name === branches[name][child] && i.target === name;
        });
        tree.children[child].desc = x.desc;
      }
    }
    return tree;
  }
  if (tree.name === root) {
    tree.desc = root;
  }
  for (var i in tree) {
    console.log(i);
  }
  return tree;
} // JavaScript name code
var a = toJSON(arry);

console.log(JSON.stringify(a, null, 2));
```